# Springboot @ServerEndpoint failed to connection

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

**I'm having trouble using spring with @ServerEndPoint annotated class**

Dev tool console said *WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/room/1' failed: *
Server console doesn't say anything.

Origin in a request header is `http://localhost:8080` so cross origin is not cause.
What is wrong ?
Thank you.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'com.jp.ichi'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.webjars:webjars-locator-core'
    implementation 'org.webjars:sockjs-client:1.5.1'
    implementation 'org.webjars:stomp-websocket:2.3.4'
    implementation 'org.webjars:bootstrap:5.2.3'
    implementation 'org.webjars:jquery:3.6.4'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

annotated class

```
package com.jp.ichi.demo;

import jakarta.websocket.*;
import jakarta.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import java.util.*;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/room/{roomId}")
public class RoomEndpoint {
    private static final Map<String,Set<Session>> sessionMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("on open");
        Set<Session> set = sessionMap.getOrDefault("test",Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>()));
        set.add(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        String roomName = "test";
        Set<Session> set = sessionMap.get(roomName);
        if (set != null) {
            set.remove(session);
            if (set.isEmpty()) {
                sessionMap.remove(roomName);
            }
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session,String message) {
        String roomName = "test";
        Set<Session> set = sessionMap.get(roomName);
        if (set != null) {
            for (Session s : set) {
                s.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
            }
        }
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session,Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

controller

```
package com.jp.ichi.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/room/*")
    public String room() {
        return "room";
    }
}
```

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/room/1");
        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log(event.data);
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi there, Please provide full error message~